# How to bring up "Bradcrumbs" navigation bar in Netbeans 7.3

Tags: netbeans, navigation, breadcrumbs

Occasionally closed this bar with "close" button on right end and can't find any menu item or button to bring it back. Is it a bug, or there is a way to display it again without erasing Netbeans configuration?

I'm talking about this feature:
http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeans_73_NewAndNoteworthy#Breadcrumbs

(Actually, I found the way to fix it, manually editing this piece of ~./netbeans/7.3/config/Editors/Preferences/org-netbeans-modules-editor-settings-CustomPreferences.xml:

```
<entry javaType="java.lang.Boolean" name="enable.breadcrumbs" xml:space="preserve">
    <value><![CDATA[true]]></value>
</entry>)
```

Comment: Very easy. Mainmenu "View->Show Breadcrumbs"

Answer (score 7):

Click on `Show Breadcrumbs` in the `View` menu

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu that menu-view-Show Breadcrumbs does not exist, you must manually edit the xml config/preferences file